# Excel: count number of same value groups

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm interested in the number of groups of consecutive instances of a given value that occur in a column (a group being one or more consecutive instances of that value).

For the following example, in which groups of 'x' are to be counted, the answer is 3:

```
x
o
x
x
o
o
o
x
```

For the example below, the answer would be 6:

```
o
x
x
x
x
x
o
o
o
x
o
x
o
x
x
o
o
o
o
x
x
o
x
```

The values are all in 1 column.

Comment: I'd personally use another column which checks the value and outputs '1' then sum them all but this looks like homework to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **B1** enter:

```
=IF(A1="x",1,0)
```

and in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(AND(A2="x",A1<>"x"),1+MAX($B$1:B1),0)
```

and copy down.  Finally in another cell enter:

```
=MAX(B:B)
```

[image]

Comment: Just because: `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A22<>"x")*(A2:A23="x"))+(1*(A1="x"))` 8P It built of yours so I will leave it here.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Thank you!........................

Answer (score 1):

> Data > Subtotal the column, Count, at Change In 'o' or 'x'

Do a Subtotal on the column of interest. It doesn't matter if the Subtotal assumes 'o' or 'x', either will suffice. After the subtotal is selected, choose, at change in 'o' or 'x' (it will depend on which is first in the column, but it's not important which). Then Count. So that's do Count at each Chang In '?'. Now that the subtotal is done, select branch '2' at the leftmost margin in Excel. At the bottom, beneath Grand Count, enter this formula:

> =COUNTIF(A7:A35, "x Count")
>   
>   -- Where A7:A35 is the reference data/column

[image]

Answer (score 0):

B14 to B36 has this formula:

```
=IF(A14<>A15,IF(A14="x","isX",""))
```

B37 counts the isX:

```
=COUNTIF(B14:B36,"isX")
```

[image]

Comment: I only get 2 when I use this on my first example. (Also, your edit of my question changed it to the point of seeming to be a different question.)

Comment: 1) I tweaked the formula so it works if x is by itself in the first row. 2) I only rearranged your words so that it was presented in a more logical manner. I feel the layout change clarified your question without altering the intent and meaning. You're welcome to flag for moderator intervention if you disagree with my edit.

Comment: My concern was that the "number of X's that occur within a group" in your edit sounds like the number of times X appears within a group, not the number of groups of X. However, it seems that everyone who answered understood, so the edit didn't seem to cause a problem. I'll look at the updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: That's true. It certainly was better than what was originally posted, but your later revisions make your question more clear. Thanks for that.